# How do i desig na job in autosys that uses the autorep command

Tags: autosys

I have the command `autorep -J <job_name> q` to get the run timings of job.

I want to create a job that uses this command and provides the output in a `.csv` or `.txt`.

how do i try writing a job like that .

the job I created fails :

Jil below :

```
/* ----------------- JIL_EXTRACT ----------------- */ 

insert_job: JIL_EXTRACT   job_type: c 
command: autorep  -J BOX_NAME q
machine: xyz
owner: atsys@xyz
permission: gx,mx
alarm_if_fail: 1
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

It should work in simple command form, roughly as you have outlined. What failure are you seeing when the job runs? It could be a permissions issue, though if you can run the command as the same user on the same box there's a good chance it will continue to work in job form.

There are a few ways to do this, the most popular are to use the standard_out or to pipe the command into a file.

To direct the results into a file:

command: autorep -q -J BOX_NAME >> output.txt

To do it without using output redirection you can use this in the JIL:

command: autorep -q -J BOX_NAME
std_out_file: >>c:\Logs\output.txt
std_err_file: >>c:\Logs\output-error.txt

Both of these are the same in Windows and Unix, only the path to the file would be in a different format. Also keep in mind if you need to use a colon anywhere you'll need to escape it (put a backslash in front of it). Finally, you will want to make sure that the path to the autorep file is in the environment path settings. You can always run a 'set' job or check the agent log in WCC.

Good Luck!